# How to call button event from one activity to another activity for refreshing?

Tags: android, xml

On the first xml page, if I click a button it takes data from server and shows on the second xml.

On second xml using refresh button I tried to do the same. So how to do I call the button event on the first activity to execute so that it refreshes the page.

I tried reloading the same page again and it does not work.

Comment: you have to use single network class (i think your network code is in first activity)

Answer (score 0):

Create function that button on first xml page will call, then on the second xml page call the same function from the first one.